# Xgboost results in identical predictions regardless of the different explaining variables (R)

Tags: r, xgboost

I have the following train & test data, which I'm performing on it an `extreme gradient boosting algorithm`  `(Xgboost)`, using a data set with a predictor, which I know that has prediction power, though the model's prediction is constant regardless of the predictor's values:

```
library(data.table)
require(xgboost)
library(Matrix)

sparse_matrix_train = sparse.model.matrix(clicked~.-1, data = train)
sparse_matrix_train2 = sparse.model.matrix(clicked~., data = test)
bst <- xgboost(data = sparse_matrix2, label = test2$clicked, max.depth = 2,
               eta = 0.3, nthread = 20, nround = 5,objective = "binary:logistic")
sparse_matrix_test = sparse.model.matrix(~., data = test)
test$pred_res<- predict(bst, sparse_matrix_test)
```

Notice that test$pred_res have identical values:

```
test$pred_res
 [1] 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567 0.2937567
[10] 0.2937567
```

Can someone please elaborate on this one?

The data

```
train <- structure(list(clicked = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
  1L), prediction = c(0.116741800132, 0.148609212057, 0.27496222789, 
  0.0284488735744, 0.234446058524, 0.405107420156, 0.122376142849, 
  0.126600568099, 0.0636921765101, 0.385909171908), pred_res = c(0.293756693601608, 
  0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.343792468309402, 0.293756693601608, 
  0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 
  0.293756693601608)), .Names = c("clicked", "prediction", "pred_res"),
  row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
  .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1547c18>)

test <- structure(list(prediction = c(0.0553382017171, 0.158500277487, 
  0.155315011347, 0.118212821075, 0.0795492263212, 0.0272566752275, 
  0.159516005352, 0.218685440776, 0.0562459472969, 0.178293801444),
  pred_res = c(0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 
  0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 
  0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608, 0.293756693601608)),
  .Names = c("prediction","pred_res"), row.names = c(NA, -10L),
  class = c("data.table","data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x1547c18>)
```

Answer (score 1):

I loaded your data and ran your code but got:

"Error in xgb.get.DMatrix(data, label) : object 'sparse_matrix2' not found"

HTH, cousin_pete

Comment: Sorry,I could not see your edit. May I suggest that you write your question in a way that is easy to reproduce the error? Your 'train' and 'test' sets etc can be dug out but why not make it easier for others to help? So first library(xgboost) then 'train' set either as data.frame or matrix format then 'test' set similarly then the code you used. Ideally we should be able to just copy/paste your question into R and see the output. Do that with your question and data as it now stands here and you will see what I mean.